# Grails' implementation of bidirectional one-to-one relationship at the database level

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've two domain classes which are bonded with a bidirectional one-to-one relationship to each other, this being implemented using **hasOne**.

```
class AssessmentData {

    static hasOne = [assessmentField:AssessmentField, assessment:Assessment]

    AssessmentField field
}


class Assessment {
   AssessmentData assessmentData
}
```

But I'm quite a bit confused about the way Grails implements this relationship at the database level. As described [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html), it simply sets the foreign key at the child domain class only, in my case, to the `Assessment` and `AssessmentField` tables. Its my primitive instinct that both tables should have a foreign key referring to each other in order to establish a one-to-one bidirectional relationship. But since this is not the case, I wanna know how this is achieved by Grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its my primitive instinct that both tables should have a foreign key referring to each other in order to establish a one-to-one bidirectional relationship

Your instincts have failed you. The domain described in your question will generate these 2 database tables:

```
assessment_data
----------------    
id


assessment
----------------
id
assessment_data_id
```

Using SQL we can get the `assessment` associated with an `assessment_data` with id 4

```
select * from assessment where assessment_data_id = 4
```

We can also go the other way and get the `assessment_data` associated with an `assessment` with id 5 using

```
select ad.* from assessment_data ad
inner join assessment a ON a.assessment_data_id = ad.id
where a.id = 5
```

So if we can "go both ways" in SQL, then we can do it with HQL, criteria queries, dynamic finders, etc. because these all ultimately get translated to SQL.

Comment: That said, the relational data at the database level is always bidirectional regardless of unidirectional/bidirectional GORM mapping between the two domain classes as the unidirectional mapping would produce the same schema effect. So in the case of unidirectional mapping, Grails doesn't facilitate us of the `join` between two domain classes? And is there a way to find out the ultimate SQL generated by Grails at runtime for the dynamic finders,  HQL and criteria queries?

Comment: If you specify a unidirectional GORM mapping it means you can only navigate between the objects in one direction, but you can always go both ways in the database. If you want to see the SQL generated by Grails you can either turn on query logging at the database level, or there are various Hibernate query loggers that will do it at the application layer

Comment: Thanks Don...really appreciate your help...and now my instincts won't fail me.